# Assistance needed in automating the process of populating a word template from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, automation, ms-word

I'm a complete newbie to VBA and would really appreciate some help automating a process, if anyone would be so kind. :)

I am trying to populate a Word template from an excel spreadsheet I have created

I have found some code which emables me to open my Word template, but that's as far as I'm capable of going :( lol

```
Private Sub PrintHDR_Click()

Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\HDR.dotx"

End Sub
```

The next step I wish to achieve is to copy and paste data from certain cells into my Word document.

I have set up the bookmarks in Word and have named the cells I wish to copy.

Some cells contain text, other cells contain formulas / sums which produce a numerical answer. In the cells that contain formulas or sums, it is the answer which I want copied to Word.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Duncan

Comment: Mailmerge can do this.

Comment: Do both bookmarks and named ranges have the same (matching) names?- give an example. Do you want to run it for all bookmarks or all named ranges? in other words- what will define scope of your macro?

Comment: Hi KazJaw, thanks for the message. Yes I have used the same name for the bookmark and the named cell. For instance my 1st bookmark is called Sample_1 and I have used this to name the cell from which I want to export the data. I have 7 bookmarks which I wish to transfer data to and each bookmark has a sister cell in excel by the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I have code that does something like this. In Word, instead of using bookmarks for the fields to replace, I just use a special marker (like `<<NAME>>`).

You may have to adapt. I use a ListObject (the new Excel "Tables"), you can change that if you use a simple Range.

Create a "Template.docx" document, make it read-only, and place your replaceable fields there (`<<NAME>>`, etc.). A simple docx will do, it doesn't have to be a real template (dotx).

```
Public Sub WriteToTemplate()
    Const colNum = 1
    Const colName = 2
    Const colField2 = 3
    Const cBasePath = "c:\SomeDir"

    Dim wordDoc As Object, sFile As String, Name As String
    Dim lo As ListObject, theRow As ListRow
    Dim item As tItem

    Set lo = ActiveCell.ListObject
    Set theRow = ActiveCell.ListObject.ListRows(ActiveCell.Row - lo.Range.Row)
    With theRow.Range
        'I use one of the columns for the filename:
        Debug.Print "writing " & theRow.Range.Cells(1, colName).text

        'A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:     \ / : * ? " < > |
        Name = Replace(.Cells(1, colName), "?", "")
        Name = Replace(Name, "*", "")
        Name = Replace(Name, "/", "-")
        Name = Replace(Name, ":", ";")
        Name = Replace(Name, """", "'")

        sFile = (cBasePath & "\" & Name) & ".docx"
        Debug.Print sFile

        Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")

        If Dir(sFile) <> "" Then 'file already exists
            Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(sFile)
            wordApp.Visible = True
            wordApp.Activate
        Else 'new file
            Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(cBasePath & "\" & "Template.docx")
            wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute Forward:=(wordApp.Selection.Start = 0), FindText:="««NUM»»", ReplaceWith:=.Cells(1, colNum)

            wordApp.Selection.Collapse direction:=1 'wdCollapseEnd
            wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="««NAME»»", ReplaceWith:=.Cells(1, colName)

            wordApp.Selection.Collapse direction:=1 'wdCollapseEnd
            wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="««FIELD2»»", ReplaceWith:=.Cells(1, colField2)

            wordDoc.ListParagraphs.item(1).Range.Select
            wordApp.Selection.Collapse direction:=1 'wdCollapseEnd
            wordApp.Visible = True
            wordApp.Activate
            On Error Resume Next
            'if this fails (missing directory, for example), file will be unsaved, and Word will ask for name.
            wordDoc.SaveAs sFile 'Filename:=(cBasePath & "\" & .Cells(1, colName))
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This basically replicates the Mail Merge function in code, to give you more control.